# Persistent do not disturb toggle in Yosemite possible?

Tags: macos, do-not-disturb

When Do Not Disturb is on it shows in Notification Center.
When it's off, no toggle.

I just want it there all the time so I can flick it on while I focus for an hour or so.

Anyone know how to make that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scroll up the Notification Center to reveal the switch.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may notice that the notification center icon is greyed out when DND is active. You can also option + click the notification center icon to toggle DND on/off.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also ENABLE the keyboard shortcut for it.

To do so go to the syst pref keyboard shortcuts.

[image: on/off]