# Turning Off Notifications While Presenting

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, settings

On Yosemite how can I turn off notifications on Yosemite while presenting or showing the screen to someone?

I know I can set the do not disturb for a time period but I was wondering if there is just an on off switch without having to set a time.

Comment: did you try the Syst pref - Notifications, in there either use the Do Not Disturb -time or the when Mirroring ect...

Comment: That's it!  I was looking on the Notifications tab.  But they put the Do Not Disturb switch on the Today tab for some strange reason.

Comment: You can also use a keyboard shortcut-- find it in syst pref -keyboard shortcuts (and set it to what you like) to turn on/off.

Comment: there should be a way to auto pause notifications during presnetations/calls

Answer (score 11):

- Simplest way is <kbd>Option (⌥)</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> Notification Centre button; top right corner. It should make the NC dim. [image: On] ⟶ [image: Off]
- Open NC then go to Today tab scroll up, it should show Do Not Disturb button, just turn it on.
  [image: Do Not Disturb]
- @Buscar웃 said you can also turn on the keyboard shortcut in System Prefs -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts.

Answer (score 6):

You can either use the System preferences- Notifications- and use one of the options there that suits your need to turn OFF.

Or you can use keyboard shortcuts, in the syst pref- keyboard- shortcuts, and assign a short cut that will turn On/Off the Notification (keyboard is faster) but you have to remember the short cut.

[image: do not disturb]

There is also this method https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/154563/46541